# How to move a Game prefab in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is my code but I don't know why when the `_lazerPrefab` spawns it doesn't move, even though `_lazerSpeed != 0`. I dont't know where the problem is.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    Instantiate(_lazerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    _lazerPrefab.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _lazerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only moving the `_lazerprefab` when `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` is true.

If you want to move the `gameObject` more than once after you press space you would need to add the move code into the gameObjects `Update()` Method itself.

You would need to attach this script to the `_lazerprefab` GameObject.

**Example Script:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObstacles : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private float _lazerSpeed = 10f;

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _lazerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

We are now able to just call the `Instantiate()` Function and the instantiated `GameObject` will move automatically each frame.

**Example Move Call:**

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    Instantiate(_lazerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot move the prefab itself, as prefabs are like "blueprints" that are used to construct real object instances, hence the name. You can indeed move those instances. Instantiate() will return the reference to the newly created copy/instance!

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    GameObject new_lazer = Instantiate(_lazerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    new_lazer.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _lazerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

But this code will always spawn a new instance when you press Space. And once you spawned a 2nd, you will no longer move the first as the `Translate` call for the first instance is not done anymore.

So you need to adapt your logic. Either put a "move/accelerate forward" script on the lazers, or keep the references returned from `Instantiate()` in a list and maintain them and their lifetime. Another way could be adding a RigidBody and giving it a velocity so it keeps moving on it's own. Impact can be handled with a collider and the OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter (if the collider is marked as trigger) functions, where you can trigger sounds, damage etc.